# Python - How to wake up a sleeping process- multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to wake up a sleeping process ?

The time (t) for which it sleeps is calculated as `t = D/S` . Now since `s` is varying, can increase or decrease, I need to increase/decrease the sleeping time as well. The speed is received over a UDP procotol. So, how do I change the sleeping time of a process, keeping in mind the following:-

```
If as per the previous speed `S1`, the time to sleep is `(D/S1)` . 
Now the speed is changed, it should now sleep for the new time,ie (D/S2). 
Since, it has already slept for D/S1 time, now it should sleep for D/S2 - D/S1.
```

How would I do it?

As of right now, I'm just assuming that the speed will remain constant all throughout the program, hence not notifying the process. But how would I do that according to the above condition?

```
def process2():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    time.sleep(secs1)
    # send some packet1 via UDP
    time.sleep(secs2)
    # send some packet2 via UDP
    time.sleep(secs3)
    # send some packet3 via UDP
```

Also, as in threads,

1) **threading.activeCount():** Returns the number of thread objects that are active.

2) **threading.currentThread():** Returns the number of thread objects in the caller's thread control.

3) **threading.enumerate():** Returns a list of all thread objects that are currently active.

What are the similar functions for getting `activecount`, `enumerate` in multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet tested but, i think this could work :

1. Instead of using sleep, create a [condition object](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#conditions) and use it's wait() method.
2. Create a [Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object, which call the notify() method of the condition object when timed out.
3. If you want to change the sleep time, just discard the old Timer (with cancel() method), and create a new Timer.

*** UPDATE ***

I just tested this and it works.

This is the wait() in the process, don't forge to acquire it first.

```
def process(condition):
    condition.acquire()
    condition.wait()
    condition.release()
```

and this is wake_up function, called from main process :

```
def wake_up(condition):
    condition.acquire()
    condition.notify()
    condition.release()
```

and create and pass a condition object when creating a process (in your main, or other functions) :

```
    condition=multiprocessing.Condition(multiprocessing.Lock())
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(condition,))
    p.start()
```

create a Timer (this timer thread will be created on main process) :

```
    timer=threading.Timer(wake_up_time, wake_up, args(condition,))
    start_time=time.time()
    timer.start()
```

if you want to change the time, just stop it and make a new Timer :

```
    timer.cancel()
    elapsed_time=time.time-start_time
    timer=threading.Timer(new_wake_up_time-elapsed_time, wake_up, args(condition,))
    timer.start()
```

Comment: I want to implement this using multi-processing , not threads because of the GIL.

Comment: the problem with this method is, it depend on Timer thread on the main process. i don't know any other method.

Comment: Though you've elaborated it enough, but I didnt understand. Please explain. Thanks

Comment: On `def process(condition):` you don't need to release the lock after `condition.wait()` because wait() function already releases the lock (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Condition -> This method releases the underlying lock, and then blocks until it is awakened by a notify() or notify_all() call for the same condition variable )